# pycharm does not accept html file

Tags: html, django, django-templates, pycharm, editor

I use the Django authentication system, and for this I created a template, named this file login.html and in the registration directory. I already had a file with this name (login.html), and then I created this file and deleted the previous file, now pycharm does not accept the new file as html, and because of this I can not put Django template in this file and Leave a link.

And you know you can't rename the file, because then the Django template authentication system can't find it. And now I do not know what to do.

What can I do to make pycharm accept this as html?

Comment: You definitely *can* rename the template name. How do you include the authentication system in your `urls.py`?

Comment: path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),           and templates: registration: login.html

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot? It is not clear what do you mean by "does not accept".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `login.html` has HTML file type and not e.g. Text one in **Settings | Editor | File Types**.

Comment: And we add another type => namefile.html or namefile.suffix

Answer (score 0):

You Can simply rename this html file from `login.html` for example to `login_users.html`